# mp4 h264 as PES payload

Tags: android, mediarecorder, mpeg2-ts

Since recording with MediaRecorder in TS format (OutputFormat=8) is deprecated, indeed, it seems to work only for a few devices, I'd like to record an **MP4/H.264** video and then to convert it to a **.ts** file by software. I must record using as output file a file descriptor because I need to send live video to a local server. 
 Until now, I've been able to produce a .ts file containing proper SI tables (PAT, PMT) with a suitable frequency (as I read somewhere, every 100 ms for PATs and every 400 ms for PMTs) while during these intervals I actually fill the .ts file with null packets. Now, I must replace these null packets with **PES**s (Packetized Elementary Streams). The question is: 
are the MediaRecorder output bytes *already* formatted as a PES? That is, could I *straightaway* split these bytes into 184-bytes chunks and use them as TS packets payload?? If not, what kind of 'pre-processing' should I have to subject them to? Is it correct to use H264 coding and MP4 container?

Comment: Hi Luigi Renda, I'm fighting to go the same thing, did you got it if yes, can you post the solution here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. PES Has a header that thay must be written first. You will also need to convert form MP4 NALUs to annex-b by writing start codes and removing NALLength (unless media recorder already does this). You must also make sure SPS and PPS are repeated in the stream. And finally, you must make sure AUDs are present as they are optional in MP4 but required for ts.

Oh, and don't forget to write PCR.

Comment: Can you explain me something more? I don't know what SPS, PPS, AUD are... You said SPS and PPS must be repeated, but at which rate? Is there any guide about it?

Comment: Any place where you want/need random access. Before every iframe is a good rule of thumb,